# Prove that $ T $ is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ an operator over $V$ given by
$$ T(x_{1}, x_{2}) = \left(\displaystyle\frac{x_1}{2}+x_2, \displaystyle\frac{x_1}{4} + \displaystyle\frac{x_2}{2}\right).$$

Prove that $ T $ is an operator symmetric.

Has my book any mistake? But $T$ is not a symmetric operator, because $\langle T(\alpha_1,\alpha_2),(\beta_1,\beta_2)\rangle \neq \langle(\alpha_1,\alpha_2),T(\beta_1,\beta_2)\rangle$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you mean symmetric operator?

Comment: What is your inner product?

Comment: It is safe to assume the standard two-element inner product in situations like this.

Comment: I'm with @i.a.m below. There is some sort of error in your text. This is not a symmetric operator.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming we are in the real case, We say $T$ is symmetric if $T^t$ the transpose of $T$ equals to $T$. you can view your operator as this matrix $$T=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \end{array} \right) $$ but $$T^t=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
1 & \frac{1}{2} \end{array} \right)\ne T$$which implies that $T$ is not symmetric.

Comment: I think you're assuming that $\{x_1, x_2\}$ forms an orthonormal basis (which is not necessarily an unreasonable assumption.)

Comment: What do you mean? Of course they're an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @JasonDeVito   I didn't assume anything about $\{x_1,x_2\}$, I just used the slandered bases for $\Bbb R^2 $ namely $(1,0),(0,1)$ to find the matrix of $T$

Comment: @i.a.m.  But if there's a different inner product from the "usual" dot product, then $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ need not be orthonormal.  All I'm really saying is that the book is not necessarily mistaken (though I agree that it likely is.)

Comment: Under the circumstances it seems unnecessarily pedantic to assume anything but the standard dot product.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, you are welcome to offer, as an answer, a different basis and/or inner product under which this operator is actually symmetric.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Oh, I see what you mean, I assumed the usual dot product you are right, but I did't see a reason not to.

Comment: @Michael:  I don't see how such an suggestion would help answer the question.  I merely pointed out one, admittedly unlikely, scenario in which $T$ *is* a symmetric operator.  I agree it's "pedantic", and perhaps even "unnecessarily" so.

Comment: @i.a.m:  I agree that there is no compelling reason not to, except that, as you showed, the question is wrong under that assumption.  Of course, mistakes in textbooks happen all the time...

Comment: @JasonDeVito thank you for pointing this out, maybe a different inner product will make it symmetric.

Comment: (Not that anyone really cares, but if declare $(1,0)$ to have a length squared of $1/8$ and $(0,1)$ to have a length squared of $1/2$, and keep them orthogonal, then $T$ is symmetric ;-).  *Now* I'm definitely being unnecessarily pedantic.)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies to Mr. DeVito for being cranky. I do think it is reasonable to assume a standard inner product or an orthonormal basis here. In fact, I think it is unreasonable *not* to do so unless specifically suggested.

But then I was intrigued: is there an inner product that would allow the operator $T$, as defined, to be considered symmetric? Yes.

Consider the matrix form of $T$ as defined by i.a.m, and an inner product 
$$\langle (a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2) \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \end{bmatrix} Q \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
where $Q$ is a $2\times 2$ positive definite matrix. The inner product test yields
$$\langle y,Tx \rangle = \langle Ty,x \rangle ~\forall x,y \quad\Longrightarrow\quad QT=T^TQ.$$
I'll leave the derivations out, but it turns out the only necessary condition on $Q$, besides positive definiteness, is $q_{22} = 4 q_{11}$. So for instance,
$$Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
QT = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} = T^TQ.$$

Comment: Funny that I posted a comment on i.a.m.'s answer coming up with a particular scale of your answer ;-).  Apology accepted - and I thought I made it clear that I, too, think it's "unreasonable *not* to do so unless specifically suggested."  Perhaps it's getting too late and I'm communicating poorly :-).  +1 from me (for both of you.)

Comment: I'm telling you, I would have voted it up if you had posted it yourself... too late :-)